# PHP CLI logs error to file but PHP via apache does not

Tags: php, apache, logging

I'm trying to log PHP errors to a log file. I did the necessary changes in php.ini and adjusted permissions of the log file to 777. PHP CLI logs okay but via apache does not.

- I know the php.ini used is the right one. I have one file for both CLI and php via apache.
- I created the log file, and for testing I set the permissions to 777.
- I generated an error on a php file but nothing got logged.
- I also tried phpinfo() in the same file that generated the error, to check if the values were correct.

php.ini:

```
error_log = /var/log/httpd/php.log
log_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

versions:

```
[user@host httpd]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 13 2013 17:29:28

[user@host httpd]# php -v
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2013 08:57:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I went already trough all similar questions but no luck. Specially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209729/apache-does-not-log-php-errors), where the solution was setting the full path of the log in php.ini. This is not the case.

Comment: what happens if you set the logging in the file itself?

Comment: @Dagon, which file you mean?

Comment: any php file you want to use to test if its going to work

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have chroot-ed apache or something "helpfull" redirection from systemd.

I had same problem and just searched system for the file name.

```
# find / -name apay_api.log 2>/dev/null
/mnt/FAST/tmp/systemd-private-edd1fc8681054769ac401c6bd8358fdd-apache2.service-mP51C4/tmp/apay_api.log
```

So it is may be your case too.

Cause is

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

in file like /usr/lib64/systemd/system/apache2.service.

Answer (score 0):

Apache sets own log files if php works as its module. In other words, it's depend on apache settings. Try to find "Log" option in apache configuration files.